# Fails to load moonlight out or browser application in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, out-of-browser, moonlight

I have implemented a out of browser feature using silverlight 4 and it is working fine in Microsoft environment. 
While i am testing the same page in linux (ubuntu) environment, the out-of-browser application installed perfectly in linux env but while opening the application it is showing the following error.

There was an error launching the application. 
Details: Failed to execute child process "/home/lenovo/.mozilla/firefox/x9y2ruwx.default/extensions/moonlight@novell.com/plugins/moonlight/lunar-launcher" (Permission denied)

You can test with the following url:
http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/out-of-browser/demo/

The following are my testing environments: 
OS: ubuntu 10.10 
Browser: Mozilla firefox 3.6 with Moonlight plug-in Version 4.0.51204.0

Can you tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged this (lunar-launcher doesn't know where to find libmoonplugin.so). I'm about to commit a fix to git master, so the next nightly build should solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your fix, I have tested with the moonlight nightly build. the Out Of Browser functionality is working fine but the basic texbox control is not displaying. Check with the following link "http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx", This sample is having textbox, label and button. But in linux i am able to see label and button not text box. Can you look into this issue.

Comment: Link is not working in the above comment please consider this as a sample link [link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx)